# Global planner for multiple robots

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there a global planner that would take into account multiple robots' locations and multiple goals? Or is there an interface to move_base that would enable writing one?

The nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner is not flexible enough for something like that as it accepts only the initial and final position as the arguments.
Any ideas how to achieve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237796/global-planner-for-multiple-robots/) by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 526 on 2016-06-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, there is none. You would need to write this planner yourself. As this planner, however, will need to run once providing paths for all robots at the same time, this will probably need to be some kind of multi-master system.
`move_base` is  intended for single robots. So I'd follow those steps:

1. setup multi robot system
2. write standalone global planner providing the paths for all robots
3. [write global planner plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS) for `move_base` that takes as input directly the plan for this specific robot from the above global planner. You can use whatever mechanism you want, Topic, Service, Action, ...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-06-23**:
sounds like a nice idea. but how would I identify robot once inside global planner plugin? only based on position or is there some other possibility?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-06-23**:
depends how you set up the multi-robot (and thus ROS multimaster) system. Probably through a namespace. I am not sure, but i think this is more or less how it is done in [rocon](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon/)